# how can I add animated shadow on my flag?

Tags: unity, shaderlab

this is my flag:

[image]

I need to adding shadow effect on my animated flag like below image but I don't know how can I do this:

[image]

here is my shader:

```
Shader "Custom/Flag" {
    Properties {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Ambient ("Ambient", Range(0., 1.)) = 0.2
        [Header(Waves)]
        _WaveSpeed("Speed", Range(1,50)) = 20
        _WaveStrength("Strength", Range(0.0, 1.0)) = 0.0
    }

        SubShader {
        Cull Off
        CGPROGRAM

        #pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows vertex:vert

        #pragma target 3.0

        struct Input {
          float4 pos : POSITION;
          float2 uv_MainTex: TEXCOORD0;
        };

        struct VertexInput{

          float4 vertex : POSITION;
          float4 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
          float3 normal : NORMAL;

        };

            float _Ambient;
            sampler2D _MainTex;

            // Compute the diffuse light
            fixed3 diffuseLambert(float3 normal)
            {
                float diffuse = max(_Ambient, dot(normalize(normal), _WorldSpaceLightPos0.xyz));
                return _LightColor0.rgb * diffuse;
            }
            float _WaveStrength;
            float _WaveSpeed;

            // Deformation
            float4 movement(float4 pos, float2 uv) {
                float sinOff = (pos.x + pos.y + pos.z) * _WaveStrength +_Time.z;
                float t = _Time.y * _WaveSpeed;
                float fx = uv.x;
                float fy = uv.x * uv.y;
                pos.x += sin(t * 1.45 + sinOff) * fx * 0.5;
                pos.y = sin(t * 3.12 + sinOff) * fx * 0.5 - fy * 0.9;
                pos.z -= sin(t * 2.2 + sinOff) * fx * 0.2;
                return pos;
            }

        void vert (inout VertexInput v, out Input o){
            UNITY_INITIALIZE_OUTPUT(Input,o);

            float sinOff=v.vertex.x+v.vertex.y+v.vertex.z;
            float t=_Time*_WaveSpeed;
            float fx=v.texcoord.x;
            float fy=v.texcoord.x*v.texcoord.y;

            v.vertex.x+=sin(t*1.45+sinOff)*fx*0.5;
            v.vertex.y=sin(t*3.12+sinOff)*fx*0.5-fy*0.9;
            v.vertex.z-=sin(t*2.2+sinOff)*fx*0.2;

              o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos( v.vertex );
              o.uv_MainTex = v.texcoord ;
        }
        void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o) {
            o.Albedo = tex2D(_MainTex,IN.uv_MainTex);
        }
        ENDCG
    } 
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

---

**Update:**

finally I use normal vector for shading but shadow isn't smooth how can I fix this:

```
v.normal.x+=sin(t*1.45+sinOff)*fx*0.5;
v.normal.y+=sin(t*3.12+sinOff)*fx*0.5-fy*0.9;
v.normal.z-=sin(t*2.2+sinOff)*fx*0.2;
```

[image]

Comment: You might want to use [shadow mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_mapping).